# How to extract square roots of polynomials in several variables?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, algorithms

The standard algorithm for extracting square roots can be used to extract the square root of a polynomial of even degree if it has one square root. Also, one can use the method of indeterminate coefficients to extract square roots of polynomials in one variable.

I've tried to use this last process to extract square roots of polynomials in two variables. I've succeed, but I am unable to precise the exact rules behind the method. For example, the following polynomial has, by construction, a square root:

$1089 p^6 z^4 + 726 p^3 w^4 x^2 y z^2 - 66 p^3 x^3 y^6 z^3 + 121 w^8 x^4 y^2 - 22 w^4 x^5 y^7 z + x^6 y^{12} z^2
$

What type of algorithm that works for polynomials in any number of variables should I apply to extract square roots? How exactly such algorithm can be applied to the polynomial written above?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 1):

start at highest (total) degree, 20: 
$$ \left(x^3 y^6 z \right)^2 = x^6 y^{12} z^2   $$

There is no other degree 20 term, and the next lower is degree 17, $-22 w^4 x^5 y^7 z.$ This degree 17 term is a multiple of $x^3 y^6 z$ which means we can put a second term to take care of 17:

$$  \left(x^3 y^6 z -11 w^4 x^2 y  \right)^2 =  x^6 y^{12} z^2-22 w^4 x^5 y^7 z +  121 w^8 x^4 y^2   $$ meaning that the three right hand terms of the original expression are a square all by themselves, the term we got for free of degree 14.

We are left with highest degree 15 at $-66p^3 x^3 y^6 z^3.$ This is, once again, divisible by  $x^3 y^6 z,$ and suggests adding in a term to take care of this 15 and seeing what happens.

$$ \left(x^3 y^6 z -11 w^4 x^2 y -33  p^3 z^2\right)^2 =  x^6 y^{12} z^2 - 22 w^4 x^5 y^7 z + 121 w^8 x^4 y^2 - 66 p^3 x^3 y^6 z^3 + 726 p^3 w^4 x^2 y z^2 + 1089 p^6 z^4$$

Comment: I saw what I now think was an inadvertent post that had only part of what I see now.  Maybe it was a glitch in the site.  Comment deleted.

Comment: Thanks. So let me see if I understand this correctly: 1) what I should do is to see the highest power, and then the lower next degree, etc., without paying attention to the variables, but only to degrees, and dividing by the square root of the first term (supposing that this will always work if the polynomial has an exact square root). Is this correct? And 2) If this procedure fails, it means the polynomial doesn't have a square root. Is that right?

Comment: @JohnFinkelstein I did what was appropriate for the polynomial you presented. Concluding that something does not have a square root is  more complicated. If, however, your highest degree term had been $ w^5 x^5 y^5 z^5,$ then no square root. If there are several terms in each degree, more work is required.

Comment: @JohnFinkelstein for contrast, $2w^5 x^5y^5z^5 + w^{10} y^{10}+  x^{10} z^{10}$ has a square root, $ w^{5} y^{5}+  x^{5} z^{5}$